# elastic search how to add to _source new created property

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I added new property (plumbsList) to abonents-physical/_mapping[image]

But how to add it to --> abonents-physical/abonents-physical/_search   <---- ? Because for now there is no such source, so when when I search I do not find any values related to plumbsList

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: You don't need to. Whenever a document has a value against the newly added field you will have that in the response as well.

Comment: Thank you for answer, But could you please clarify for me as I'm completely new to elastiSearch. By  "document has a value" you mean,  in my case if it has plumbsList property?

Comment: The new property will have null value for documents that were indexed before you added the new property. Therefore you don't get the property in response of _search call.